# Having Trouble with Entity Framework. Adding a new row

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce-3.5

Having Trouble with Entity Framework. I have been adding a new row to Iktato table but is not work.

```
CREATE TABLE [Iktato] (
[TIPACT] nvarchar(3), 
[NRINREG] int NOT NULL identity(1,1), 
[DATAINREG] datetime, 
[NRACT] nvarchar(10), 
[DATAACT] datetime, 
[CODARHIVA] nvarchar(20), 
[NRFILE] int, 
[NRANEXE] int, 
[EMITENT] nvarchar(50), 
[TERMEN] datetime, 
[RESP1] nvarchar(50), 
[RESP2] nvarchar(50), 
[RESP3] nvarchar(50), 
[RESP4] nvarchar(50), 
[DESCRIERE] ntext, 
[PRIORITATE] nvarchar(13), 
[STATUT] nvarchar(20), 
[FILENAME] nvarchar(128),
PRIMARY KEY (NRINREG)
)
GO


CREATE TABLE [rasp] (
[TIPACT] nvarchar(3), 
[NRINREG] int NOT NULL, 
[DATAINREG] datetime, 
[NRACT] nvarchar(10), 
[DATAACT] datetime, 
[CODARHIVA] nvarchar(20), 
[NRFILE] int, 
[NRANEXE] int, 
[EMITENT] nvarchar(50), 
[TERMEN] datetime, 
[RESP1] nvarchar(50), 
[RESP2] nvarchar(50), 
[RESP3] nvarchar(50), 
[RESP4] nvarchar(50), 
[DESCRIERE] ntext, 
[PRIORITATE] nvarchar(13), 
[STATUT] nvarchar(20), 
[FILENAME] nvarchar(128),  
[ROW_ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
PRIMARY KEY (ROW_ID)
)
GO


ALTER TABLE rasp 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Iktato 
FOREIGN KEY (NRINREG) 
REFERENCES Iktato (NRINREG) ON DELETE CASCADE 

GO
```

It`s a sequence of my program:

```
private RegistruEntities entities;
private Iktato proba;

proba = new Iktato { NRINREG = 5 };
entities.AttachTo("Iktatoes", proba);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

I want to insert a row with registration number 5 which will be saved in the database Iktato.
Save it not work.

Please help !

Comment: How does it *not work* ? Do you get an error - if so: **what** error? Also: can you show us your connection string used for this app?

Comment: No errors but not inserted a new row in my Iktato table ! I use sqlce 3.5 .

A delete row work ok. Here the code:

       private void delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (iktatoesViewSource.View.CurrentPosition >= 0)
            {
                int wval1 = Convert.ToInt32(nRINREGLabel.Content);

                proba = entities.Iktatoes.Single(iktato => iktato.NRINREG == wval1);
                
                entities.DeleteObject(proba);
                entities.SaveChanges();
                iktatoesViewSource.DeferRefresh();
            }
        }

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: No errors but not inserted a new row in my Iktato table ! I use sqlce 3.5 .

Answer (score 1):

New entities have to be inserted using `AddObject`, not `AttachTo`:

```
proba = new Iktato { NRINREG = 5 };
entities.AddObject("Iktatoes", proba);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

You should also have an `ObjectSet<Iktato>` as a member of your ObjectContext that allows to use a more strongly typed version to avoid the string `"Iktatoes"` for the entity set:

```
proba = new Iktato { NRINREG = 5 };
entities.Iktatoes.AddObject(proba);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. It Works for me

```
public ItemCategory Create(ItemCategory objItemCategory)
    {            
        context.ItemCategory.Add(objItemCategory);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return objItemCategory;
    }
```